# SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma

Tags: oracle

I get the following error when I tried to insert my data into oracle using Oracle SQL Developer tool.

Error at Command Line:54 Column:2
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
*Cause:
*Action:

I couldn't find any mistake. My SQL as follows. Anyone can help me please?

```
INSERT INTO MS9.MYTAB(
2001_ACCOUNT_STATUS,
2001_CDP_ACCOUNT_NO,
2001_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
2001_LOGIN_FAIL_CNT,
2001_MAILING_ADDRESS_ID,
2001_MOBILE_CTY_CD,
2001_MOBILE_NO, 
2001_OFFICE_TEL_CTY_CD, 
2001_OFFICE_TEL_NO,
2001_OTP_SECURITY_CD,
2001_REGISTER_DT, 
2001_RESIDENT_ADDRESS_ID, 
2001_ID,
2001_USER_ID,
2001_USER_ID_TYPE,
 2001_USER_ID_TYPE_OTH,
 2001_USER_NAME,
 2001_USER_TYPE,
 2001_VERIFY_STATUS,
 LAST_UPDATED_TIME,
 CREATED_TIME,
 CREATED_BY,
 LAST_UPDATED_BY,
 2001_PWD_CHANGED_DT,
 TRANSACTION_ID,
 VERSION_NO)
VALUES(
'A',
null,
'jxxxxxso@baml.com',
4,
'a9a0d8a7-8ac2-4b76-a70d-08c4f188da93',
'65',
'12345678',
null,
'23456789',
'63ACF060850971EFE22928E62B9EAD==',
'42684',
'a9a0d8a7-8ac2-4b76-a70d-08c4f188da93',
'TD1611100003',
'GAxxxx678',
'P',
null,
'Name 1',
'C',
'V',
'10-Nov-16',
'10-Nov-16',
'System',
'Name 1',
'10-Nov-16',
'testtransactionid111',
9};
```

table strure as follows:

```
2001_ID                     NVARCHAR2(12 CHAR)  
2001_USER_TYPE              VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)   
2001_USER_ID_TYPE           VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)   
2001_USER_ID_TYPE_OTH       NVARCHAR2(100 CHAR) 
2001_USER_ID                NVARCHAR2(20 CHAR)  
2001_USER_NAME              NVARCHAR2(66 CHAR)  
2001_RESIDENT_ADDRESS_ID    NVARCHAR2(36 CHAR)  
2001_MAILING_ADDRESS_ID     NVARCHAR2(36 CHAR)  
2001_ACCOUNT_STATUS         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)   
2001_VERIFY_STATUS          VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)   
2001_REGISTER_DT            DATE                
2001_LOGIN_FAIL_CNT         NUMBER(2,0)         
2001_EMAIL_ADDRESS          NVARCHAR2(320 CHAR) 
2001_OFFICE_TEL_CTY_CD      VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)    
2001_OFFICE_TEL_            VARCHAR2(12 BYTE)   
2001_MOBILE_CTY_CD          VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)    
2001_MOBILE_                VARCHAR2(12 BYTE)   
2001_CDP_ACCOUNT_           VARCHAR2(12 BYTE)   
2001_OTP_SECURITY_CD        VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)   
CREATED_TIME                DATE    
CREATED_BY                  NVARCHAR2(256 CHAR) 
LAST_UPDATED_TIME           DATE    
LAST_UPDATED_BY             NVARCHAR2(256 CHAR) 
VERSION_                    NUMBER  
TRANSACTION_ID              VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)   
2001_PWD_CHANGED_DT         DATE
```

Comment: `..9};` -> `..9);`

Comment: [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/index.html) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if both implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes they use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use the correct tags.

Answer (score 3):

Your SQL statement ends with a `}` instead of a `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove curly braces (}) at the end of the query and change your query as below

```
INSERT INTO 
MS9.MYTAB
(
2001_ACCOUNT_STATUS, 2001_CDP_ACCOUNT_NO, 2001_EMAIL_ADDRESS, 2001_LOGIN_FAIL_CNT,
2001_MAILING_ADDRESS_ID, 2001_MOBILE_CTY_CD, 2001_MOBILE_NO, 2001_OFFICE_TEL_CTY_CD, 
2001_OFFICE_TEL_NO, 2001_OTP_SECURITY_CD, 2001_REGISTER_DT, 2001_RESIDENT_ADDRESS_ID, 
2001_ID, 2001_USER_ID, 2001_USER_ID_TYPE, 2001_USER_ID_TYPE_OTH,
2001_USER_NAME, 2001_USER_TYPE, 2001_VERIFY_STATUS, LAST_UPDATED_TIME,
CREATED_TIME, CREATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_BY, 2001_PWD_CHANGED_DT,
TRANSACTION_ID, VERSION_NO
 )
VALUES
(
'A', null, 'jxxxxxso@baml.com', 4,
'a9a0d8a7-8ac2-4b76-a70d-08c4f188da93', '65', '12345678', null,
'23456789', '63ACF060850971EFE22928E62B9EAD==', '42684', 'a9a0d8a7-8ac2-4b76-a70d-08c4f188da93',
'TD1611100003', 'GAxxxx678', 'P', null,
'Name 1', 'C', 'V', '10-Nov-16',
'10-Nov-16', 'System', 'Name 1', '10-Nov-16',
'testtransactionid111', 9
);
```

Comment: HI  David & Prathyush, thank you so much for all your answers. The error has been resolved.

Comment: Hi, Although the previous error resolved, there is another error come up. "SQL Error: ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month" Any idea please? I used date conversion function such as to_date('10-11-2016','dd-mm-yyyy'), it still throw the same error.